# Is there a way to tell how many lines an HTML snippet will take up when rendered?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given some HTML code, is there a way (in Ruby on Rails, in particular), to tell how many lines the HTML will take up on the screen when rendered?

-- Clarifications:
It's in an erb file, but i'm just talking about one string that will be rendered as HTML so yes, text that contains HTML tags.

-- EDIT:

The bigger picture: I want to know how tall a particular segment of the page is so I can conditionally include certain "Next/Previous" links on the bottom. These navigation links appear above the aforementioned segment, so I only want to include the links on the bottom if the segment is very tall.

Comment: Are you talking about text that contains html tags?

Comment: you mean given some erb? it depends on the erb and the data. for example, if there is an iteration inside your erb hoy many times it will be executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, no - it all will depend on the CSS being applied by the browser and the platform itself and lots of other variables. You can, however, detect the dimensions of elements once they are rendered.

**Update**
Pursuant to your edit, you pretty much need to do this on the client using JavaScript. It's actually pretty straight forward.

1. Add the Next/Previous element HTML to the page but hide it with CSS
2. Detect the height of the element in question
3. If the height is above you threshold size, display the hidden Next/Previous

With Jquery (the framework of champions):

```
//assuming a height of 200 as the threshold
var THRESHOLD_HEIGHT = 200;
if ($("#segment").height() >= THRESHOLD_HEIGHT) {
   $("#links").show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No.

How can you possibly know how wide my screen will be when I visit your website?

Comment: Perhaps there's a container element that has a set width. There's actually a serious lack of fluid width websites around, so this is a rather moot point in most cases.

Comment: @Matthew Scharley: One of the first things I do when I install a browser is to replace the hideous default font settings with something sane. (Times New Roman? Really?) You wouldn't *believe* how many websites that breaks. So, even if you know the width of the container, you still don't know which font I set up, or what kerning settings I use or whatever else influences the layout. That is, after all, the *whole point* of HTML: that *you* semantically describe the structure of your document to allow *me* to render it the way I want. Otherwise, use PDF.

Comment: Not only that but different browsers render fonts differently even on the same platform. Even if you specify character spacing, word spacing, line height, font face, font size, ... in the CSS you still can't compute the rendered size without rendering it and asking the browser how big it is.

Comment: örg As a developer, I agree with you. But as someone who works at a design company, there's ways to get most browsers to get within a couple pixels of each other. It's still not perfect, and you are correct, a browser can deign to ignore some CSS, or even add more in. 98% of the time though, you can get pretty damn close.

Answer (score 0):

Look at YUI Paginator http://s831.us/hW6Dpd

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be best off solving this problem with javascript (or even better a javascript library like jquery). You could measure the height of the div containing the text you want to paginate and dynamically break it apart and add links in the browser. There would be several ways of solving this problem but I would probably do it by sequentially chopping off paragraphs from the end and remeasuring and repeating until it was short enough. Obviously the chopped off paragraphs would have to be collected somewhere to be used for the next page (and recursively measured again in case the second page was also too long).